# Need WHMCS expert advice regarding a sub installation for a sister company?

Tags: php, whmcs

So this is the scenario. There is company A that has grown significantly over the last few years. But company A has only been targeting a specific market. Now company A realises it can offers its same services on an international level. The logical thing is to start another WHMCS installation for this new sister company, but I want more:

I want only one whmcs installation which caters for two different domains, using two different themes (i have more than one license for this purpose). I have a very good idea of how to sort out the theming, my concern is regarding support tickets, invoices being sent out etc.

So...

1. I need to know that before I embark on this journey of building this double-merged entity, that it will be possible distinguish between the two sites and the correspondance sent to them etc?
2. Also, anyone who's actually tried something like this, you'd be my hero if you could share?
3. And then also, I have a module that more less integrates Drupal with WHMCS. Does anyone see any commercial value in something like that, or should I stop being a snob, finish it, and just release it to the community? I do so see a bit more value if this plugin can even handle multi-site installation (as this is what I'm effectively triny to accomplish now)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done it, but what I would try is to add some code to configuration.php something like  "if the site is abc.com use this database"  "if the site is 123.com use this other database"

If the theme ID is stored in the database you may not even have to do anything else.

This is just a theory, I haven't tried it but it ought to work.

As for the drupal/whmcs module.  Drupal is open source, you are seeking an open answer to your question.  Make your module and set it free.

Comment: If you had two databases, how do you know which DB to use on the admin side? All you are saving in this case the disk space of having the product files duplicated and the time to do an update. I don't think 100mb is worth the risk of conflicts and things that won't work. To get the benefits of multi-site WHMCS, you need to use a shared database.

Answer (score 0):

There are third party plugins that do multi-site WHMCS installations for example:

https://marketplace.whmcs.com/product/2222 and http://www.modulesgarden.com/products/whmcs/multibrand/features

I have heard feedback on both modules but never tried either. Fundamentally you are trying to make the product do something it was not designed to do. When you do that you don't normally get as smooth as an experiance as you expect.